# Refresh Kendo Grid table after success post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm currently using Kendo Grid for ASP.Net Core MVC.

So, I created a column with a group of options.

```
columns.Template("<div class='btn-group'></div>")
                            .Title("").Width(100);
```

Then with jquery:

```
    $(this).find(".btn-group").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-light btn-sm dropdown-toggle' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>Actions<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-down'></i>. 
   </button>
<ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end'>
    <li>
     <a class='dropdown-item text-danger is-active' onclick='showSweetAlert(" + dataItem.AdvertiserId+", " + dataItem.IsActive +")' type='button'>Mark Inactive</a>
    </li>
</ul>");
```

As you can see I use `onclick` function to show up [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) library

The code:

```
function showSweetAlert(id, isActive){
     if (isActive) {
        Swal.fire({
            title:"Are you sure?",
            text:"This will inactivate advertiser!",
            icon:"warning",
            showCancelButton:!0,
            confirmButtonColor:"#2ab57d",
            cancelButtonColor:"#fd625e",
            confirmButtonText:"Inactivate",
        }).then(function(result){
            if(result.isConfirmed){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/Advertisers/ActiveAdvertiser?id='+id+'&isActive='+!isActive,
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function(r){
                        Swal.fire("Inactivated!", "Advertiser inactivated successfully", "success");
                    },
                    error: function (request) {
                        console.log(request.responseText)
                        Swal.fire("Error!", "Something went wrong, please try again`", "warning");
                        // window.location.href ='@Url.Action("Index","Advertisers")'

                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

So if button is executed I create a post action to modify values, when it finished service return `OK` or `BadRequest` if  this work well. If its success it show a new alert and then you can close the modal.

What I want to achieve is a way to refresh grid in order to get new values, is it possible to achieve that?

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> ActiveAdvertiser(int id, bool isActive)
    {
        var advertiser = await _advertisersService.GetAdvertiserByAdvertiserIdAsync(id);

        if (advertiser == null) return Json(new { result = "BadRequest" });
        var model = AssignAdvertiserViewModel(advertiser, id);
        model.IsActive = isActive;

        var result = await _advertisersService.UpdateAdvertiserAsync(model, GetCurrentUserAsync().Id);

        return Json(result != null ? new { result = "OK" } : new { result = "BadRequest" });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik UI Grid for ASP.NET MVC internally implements all of the functionality exposed by the Kendo UI Grid. Hence, you can use the [refresh() JavaScript method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/refresh) of the grid:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh(); // grid should be replaced with the Name of your grid
```

Alternatively, you can refresh the data source directly by calling the [read() method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read) of the data source.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); // grid should be replaced with the Name of your grid
```